# Move a div up when I hover over it

Tags: html, css

I have a card with some title in the middle of the card, and when I hover over the card a submit button appears on the bottom of the card. 
But what I want is the title in the bottom of the card and when I hover, the title moves to the center and the submit button appears on the buttom.

How can I move my title like that?

This is what I have:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="center">
      <a ...>{title}</a>
    </Link>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <button ...> Submit </button>
  </div>
</div>


.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;

  button {
     position: absolute;
     opacity: 0;

     :hover {
       background-color: black;
     }
  }

  :hover button {
     opacity: 1;
  }
}

 a {
   display: block;
   align-self: center;
 }

 .bottom {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
 }

 button {
   left: 0px;
   position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use the GSAP library. This is a 2 second job with TweenLite.

Comment: Keep in mind that this UX won't do well on mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest solution I can think about:

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .center{
     margin-top: 150px;
     transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .container:hover .center{
     margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .bottom{
     opacity: 0;
     visibility: hidden;
     transform: translateY(100px);
     transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .container:hover .bottom{
     opacity: 1;
     visibility: visible;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     transform: translateY(0);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

   <div class="center">
       <a>Title</a>
   </div>

   <div class="bottom">
     <button> Submit </button>
   </div>
</div>
```